# Accessing webcam in browser via http

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcam

Have problem with accessing webcam in Google Chrome via http, it allows usage of the webcam with https in most cases. Other browsers don't have such a problem.

For example yahoo gifshot gives error:

> "There was an issue with the getUserMedia API - the user probably denied permission"

and http://demo.mycodingtricks.com/javascript/webcam-api/ gives the message:

> "Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam: PermissionDeniedError: Only secure origins are allowed"

and sends us to that https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

So what can be the reason of such behavior? Browser settings are default.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added more info, hope for help.

Answer (score 3):

Already found an answer.
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins
Google Chrome does not allow accessing user personal data on insecure connection